# Reconnecting SSH Agent forwarding when resuming an interrupted screen session

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, gnu-screen, ssh-agent

So this has proved to be a very difficult thing to google.  I have a work setup where I run everything off of a laptop that I hibernate or shut down at the end of the day.  Doing so obviously cuts off my SSH session in puTTY.  After a bit of poking, I discovered a good way to auto-boot screen and pick up the disconnected session when connecting via puTTY (namely, adding `if [ -z "$STY" ]; then screen -R; fi` to the end of my .bashrc).

This works wonderfully, but I still have a problem.  I use SSH agent forwarding via Pageant on my laptop (where I initially enter the password) to secondary servers.  From what I can tell, this socket is broken when the puTTY session breaks and does not reconnect when reloading **and reconnecting to screen**.

Here's my test:

```
20:01:38 {~/test}$ git clone git@github.com:coldcandor/env.git
Cloning into 'env'...
remote: Counting objects: 1105, done.
remote: Total 1105 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1105
Receiving objects: 100% (1105/1105), 341.06 KiB | 453.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (544/544), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
20:01:43 {~/test}$ rm -rf env
```

Disconnect puTTY and reconnect

```
20:01:58 {~/test}$ git clone git@github.com:coldcandor/env.git
Cloning into 'env'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

As you can see, it doesn't preserve the forwarding.  However, if I either do not reconnect to screen, or fully exit and reopen screen after reconnecting, then it's fine.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amusingly, in the process of trying to make the solution provided by Jakuje work, I stumbled upon a git [link](https://gist.github.com/martijnvermaat/8070533) which in turn had a Superuser [post](https://superuser.com/questions/180148/how-do-you-get-screen-to-automatically-connect-to-the-current-ssh-agent-when-re/424588#424588) which had a working version of the idea.  Here's the short version:

```bash
if [ -S "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && [ ! -h "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]; then
    ln -sf "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
fi
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
```

Be sure to view that page if you want more details or other potential methods.  There is discussion there that this may not work in very specific circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

`screen` is retaining your environment variables from the first connection and the socket gets disconnected. New `ssh` session creates you a new socket, but the environment variable `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` of that session gets overwritten by the `screen` one.

Clean way how to get out would be to preserve this variable into the restored screen, but I didn't find a way to do so.

As a workaround I can think of adding few lines into your `.bashrc`:

```bash
# move auth socket to known place so even restored screen can find it
if [ -n "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]; then
  [ -f "~/.ssh/agent.socket" ] && rm -f "~/.ssh/agent.socket"
  ln "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" "~/.ssh/agent.socket"
  SSH_AUTH_SOCK="~/.ssh/agent.socket"
fi
# you already have
if [ -z "$STY" ]; then screen -R; fi
```

(didn't test it. I hope there are no syntax errors, but I believe you get my point and you can fix it -- there is edit button under my answer).

Comment: That explanation why makes perfect sense.  I'll play around with your proposal and see if it works out (coming back here to update after, of course).  Thanks!

Comment: You were on the right track!  It didn't quite work, but while trying to fix it I stumbled on a working version - see my accepted answer.  Apparently my original google-fu was not good...